# I am unable to toggle/collapse a link when put inside laravel 5

Tags: laravel-5

```
@extends('layouts.app')
  @section('content')
  <!DOCTYPE html>
  <html lang="en">
  <head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <title>siawa VPN Appliance</title>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css" integrity="sha384-rHyoN1iRsVXV4nD0JutlnGaslCJuC7uwjduW9SVrLvRYooPp2bWYgmgJQIXwl/Sp" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="bootstrap-formhelpers-countries.js"></script>
  <script src="bootstrap-formhelpers-countries.flags.css"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-Tc5IQib027qvyjSMfHjOMaLkfuWVxZxUPnCJA7l2mCWNIpG9mGCD8wGNIcPD7Txa" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>


<a class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="collapse" href="#collapseExample" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapseExample">Advanced</a>
<div class="collapse" id="collapseExample">
            <div class="container" style="margin-top:15px">
  <form class="form" action="##" method="post" id="registrationForm">
          <fieldset>
              <div class="form-group" >

                  <div class="col-xs-6" style="margin-top:15px">
                      <label class="control-label" for="Port">Port</label>
                      <input class="form-control" name="Port" id="Port" placeholder="port" title="enter your port" type="text">
                  </div></div>
</fieldset>
      </form>
      <hr>
  </div>
</div>
```

It works normally for a HTML file but when i put under @section('content') in laravel 5 it doesn't work.The following code has been added.When i click on advanced link it opens but doesn't close back if clicked again.so toggling is one sided only at the moment it opens but doesn't closes.

Comment: Is your javascript included in the page?

Comment: yes i added like this <script type="text/javascript" src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css" integrity="sha384-rHyoN1iRsVXV4nD0JutlnGaslCJuC7uwjduW9SVrLvRYooPp2bWYgmgJQIXwl/Sp" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

Comment: Can you show your actual blade files? (edit the post don't include them in the comments).

Comment: actually its quite a big file nearly 700 lines of code....The problem come when i put the html under @extends('layouts.app')
  @section('content')

Comment: Then just show the parts of the blade files that are applicable.

Comment: plz check the edited part

Comment: Why have you got the `head` section of you page inside a blade file that's extending another blade file??

Comment: plz show me how should i put ,i am a little bit confused

Comment: Have a look at https://laracasts.com/series/laravel-5-fundamentals/episodes/5 . When you're done have a quick browse over the documentation for blade as a few things have been added since this video was made (e.g. the loop variable and stacks etc): https://laravel.com/docs/master/blade